# Is it true that short stories "must" end without definite conclusions?

Tags: short-stories

In my native subcontinental literature, there is a notion that one of the identifying features of short stories is, it **must** end without a conclusion. The reader is left guessing. That is, the reader can assume anything to be the conclusion.

Is it same in English literature?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with an answer that provides a single (or a few) example(s) of English short stories with clear conclusions? Or are you hoping for more in-depth information about English short stories as a whole?

Comment: @Randal'Thor, the first one.

Comment: It is up to the author. There is no definite rule.

Answer (score 1):

A short story can, and often does, have a simple point to make.  Sometimes, though, it leaves things open on purpose because it is intended to make you think and consider - and in so doing reconsider your own assumptions.

Some examples from my own favorites:

- The point is to make a (horrible) pun, as in ["Shah Guido G."](https://www.e-reading.life/chapter.php/81709/3/Azimov_-_Buy_Jupiter_and_Other_Stories.html)   ([Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shah_Guido_G.))
- The point is to express an opinion of the (collective) behaviour of people as in ["Silly Asses"](https://www.e-reading.life/chapter.php/81709/21/Azimov_-_Buy_Jupiter_and_Other_Stories.html)  ([Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_Asses))
- Make you look at things from a new perspective as in ["Exile to Hell"](https://www.e-reading.life/chapter.php/81709/31/Azimov_-_Buy_Jupiter_and_Other_Stories.html) ([Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exile_to_Hell))
- Reconsider right and wrong as in ["Scanners Live in Vain"](https://archive.org/stream/ScannersLiveInVain/SmithCordwainer-ScannersLiveInVain.txt) ([Cordwainer Smith](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanners_Live_in_Vain))

As you can see, a short story can end unresolved and leave it to your imagination - but it can also have a definite point and end that it wants to bring you to.